# styles.xml inherit "?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"?

Tags: android, android-layout, styles

I'd like to customize some borderless ImageButtons. To avoid code duplication, I use `styles.xml`:

```
<style name="EditNotesButton" parent="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle">
    <item name="android:layout_width">25dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">25dp</item>
    <item name="android:scaleType">fitCenter</item>
</style>
```

However, the following error is thrown:

```
Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle'.
```

Is there any way to inherit *borderlessButtonStyle*?

Answer (score -11, accepted):

borderlessButtonStyle only available on API level 11 or above.

Comment: Still doesn't work on higher APIs, this answer seems to be wrong

Comment: aleung answer is working, so this answer is not the correct one, just giving additional information.

Answer (score 78):

For AppCompat, you can inherit from the parent style:

```
<style name="MyBordelessButtonStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless">
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/<your size></item>
        <!-- other items here -->
</style>
```

Based on the [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/v7/appcompat/res/values-v11/themes_base.xml)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, due to using the newest AppCompat

Answer (score 39):

**You can't inherit an attribute, you have to inherit a style.**

Choose a button borderless style which matchs your theme to inherit. All Android internal styles can be found at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.style.html

For example, your application uses Holo Light theme (specify in `AndroidManifest.xml`), then you should inherit `Widget.Holo.Light.Button.Borderless.Small` style.

```
<style name="EditNotesButton" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Button.Borderless.Small">
  <item name="android:layout_width">25dp</item>
  <item name="android:layout_height">25dp</item>
  <item name="android:scaleType">fitCenter</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use this style instead for API 11 and above:

```
<style name="EditNotesButton" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Button.Borderless" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't inherit in this way. Try this:

```
<style name="EditNotesButton" parent="@android:style/Widget">
    <!-- This will cause borderless button --> 
    <item name="android:background">@android:drawable/list_selector_background</item>
    ...
</style>
```